# How to use browserify with fonts

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, browserify, package-managers

So browserify doing everything via JavaScript at runtime, even CSS stuff.
But how I can handle fonts, like font-awesome with npm and browserify.

A npm pacakge does exist here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/font-awesome
But how can I bundle the fonts for my browser without using another tool like grunt or gulp.

// edit

If I want to use now a fa class in my html, is there another way than pointing to the `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css` in my html file?

I'm searching a automated solution, because if I have several libraries like font-awesome and they bring their own assets like fonts, images and other files, I don't want to point to every asset file by hand in my html file.

With jade I can just serve some files in `public`. And `public` contains all the assets which come via my remote dependencies, like fonts, images, ...
But how to copy or symlink all the files from the particular `node_modules` to the `public` automatically?

Comment: what do you mean "bundle". `npm install font-awesome` installs all the font-awesome stuff in the node_modules directory and you can simply set up your app to point to `./node_modules/fontawesome` as a static dir for fetching resources from. Your question kind of really needs more details like what you're using for hosting your app/site/whatever. Also, why would needing grunt/gulp be even remotely problematic? You're clearly already using node and browserify, adding Grunt/Gulp is just decent practice.

Comment: are you using anything else, or is it just a plain .html file and npm-installed fontawesome? (e.g. are you using express? are you using jekyll, etc.?)

Comment: updated my question again :) the point is, that I don't want to point all the assets by hand. So let's say I want to use express. I want a directory, for instance public, and express should serve these files static. So I need some process which copy or symlink only the needed assets to the public directory

Comment: If you use express, you say `app.static("/fonts", express.static("node_modules/fontawesome"));` and done. You now link to your fonts in css as if they live in `/fonts`, and import as `@import("/fonts/css/fontawesome.css")`. You don't copy a single thing, you just tell express to alias and then move on with your life. The important question is **what** do you use. Jade, Hapi, Express, etc. all let you do this, and their syntax is all slightly different so ask about a concrete example. Don't just ask "how do I do this" without saying what you're actually going to use.

Comment: @timaschew Are you talking about requiring fonts in the same way you would require other commonjs modules? If so then I would love to know how to do this. What I don't currently understand is if browserify can not deliver font's and CSS files to the browser then why would you ever use it? Why not just use web pack which seems to do it all.

Comment: yep, I switched to webpack and it's really great

Answer (score 4):

I know one easy way to do that. Use your fonts in Base64 format. That way the Font data is resting within the CSS itself, not in external files.

Then just load your CSS into Browserify your usual way (with modules such as "insert-css" or "cssy". I use "stylify" because I use Stylus) and as it pipes the CSS definitions, it will also carry the font data itself.

Compressing your Base64 code beforehand is also a good idea. Or maybe let Uglify do the compressing in the end. Compare results.

Do double-check your target browsers support for Base64 fonts.